# Unable to access Users/Groups in AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

On trying to access Users/Groups in AAD, I see the following error:

[image]

What could be the issue?

Comment: Ask your administaror to set **NO** for **Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal**
from AAD->UserSetting.

Comment: Can you please let me know are you a guest user or member in your Directory?

Comment: Apologize for the late response. I'm a member in my directory.

Comment: On clicking, user settings I see error: Unable to complete due to service connection error. Please try again later.

Comment: From Member account it won't be possible for do that you need admin permission. So, Ask your administaror to set NO for Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal from AAD->UserSetting

Comment: I’m the admin of a demo tenant I have. I still see the same error

Comment: In that case would suggest you to please reach out to Azure Support Team.

Comment: Hello @user989988, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your error in my environment. There Might be two reason for getting this error.

1. Considering you as Member of Azure Active Directory
   Previously I was able to access the user/group from the AAD portal.
   Once set Yes for Restrict access to Azure AD administrator portal from administrator account, I am also getting the same error as like you.

[image]

[image]

2. Considering you as a Guest User of Azure Active Directory.

   Might Your Administrator set restricted to access the properties of
   others user in own directory

[image]

[image]